# VIM Ruby Regex syntax highlighting with quotes

Tags: ruby, vim, syntax-highlighting

I wonder what I can do to fix the Ruby Regex syntax highlighting when there are quotes in the Regex?

Here is where the problem is:
[image: Regex with quotes]

And compare it to the similar where there are no quotes:
[image: Regex without quotes]

(I'm already using the latest vim-ruby plugin).

Comment: It looks like you don't have any regex highlighting at all. It's just highlighting as though it were a line of Ruby code; hence the I being blue (for constant), and $/ being red (for global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems you have some problems with vim setup (or maybe outdated version of vim) -- everything works fine for me. I have vim 7.3.346 packaged for Debian.
Standard ruby syntax files and syntax files from [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) both do the job.
If updating is not an option or doesn't help please attach output of :syntax and :script commands. Here is [a hint](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) how to simplify the proccess.

Comment: I fixed it a while ago by updating vim-ruby. Just forgot to reply here. But I'll accept your answer. You did pay some time to answer so why not.